# Realm Clone RealmQuery in different thread

Tags: android, multithreading, realm, rx-java2

How to clone RealmQuery in different thread?

**Problem:**

1. Create RealmQuery in **X** Thread.
2. Query for RealmResults is same thread.
3. If Empty Results, get data from Server in **Y** Thread.
4. Insert data to Realm in background thread (**Y**). <-- New Instance of realm
5. Re-query with same filters as in `1` in **Z** Thread.
6. Return results in Main Thread.

As of now, am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm accessed from incorrect thread.`

Tried cloning using, `RealmQuery.createQueryFromResult(RealmResults<E> queryResults)`. Internally the clone using the same realm instance of the results.

How would the clone behave if the `queryResults` was empty?

Would be better if clone can be done in RxJava2.

Answer (score 1):

> Re-query with same filters as in 1 in Z Thread.
>
> Return results in Main Thread.

Okay so this is completely unnecessary because you can create a RealmQuery and store a field reference to the RealmResults, add a RealmChangeListener to it, and when you insert into Realm on the background thread, it will automatically update the RealmResults and call the RealmChangeListener.

So you don't need to "re-query with same filters in Z thread" (because Realm's `findAllSortedAsync()` already queries on a background thread), and you don't need to manually return results in main thread because `findAllSortedAsync()` already does that.

---

Solution: use Realm's notification system (and async query API). Read the docs: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications

Comment: There is problem in this case, If someone updates the Table I will get a callback from Notification & pass it back to requester & discard the listener.
But my network request is still pending here. Else I should have a global variable which defines the success for response & then propagate to requester.

Comment: `& discard the listener.` what does that listener do? Update the UI once the operation is complete? Just observe the database layer.

Comment: You UI shouldn't care about how the data got into the DB, so just registering a `RealmChangeListener` would be the way to go. If you want some indication in the UI that the network is used, save a boolean in Realm as well and listen for that.